# php executing shell command gives random output in only in heavy use mode

Tags: php, linux, unix, fedora

Please help me with this issue that I am facing on production server. I launched an application that saves images in a directory only after checking that it does not already exist.

To check if it already exists I used the following command
`find $filePath -name $fileInitial*`

I am pretty surprised to see that it all went fine on development and QA but in real environment, out of 50 cases, in 5 cases it returns blank even if the file exists.

I tried replacing backtick operator with `exec`, `shell_exec`, `passthru`, and `system`. I even tried replacing the `find` command with `ls` but still no gain.

Please suggest what can be done?

Comment: I assume you are using a shell command because glob() or file_exists() functions do not do what you need it to do?

Comment: Given that `*` at the end, an exec() call is going make the shell look for `whatever*` and probably return a "no match" immediately before find ever has a chance to run.

Comment: @Charanjeet Kaur: Please select one of the answers it looks like your question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your code, I would strongly suggest avoiding exec/shell_exec as much as possible.

It causes a very large security risk to your whole system if not coded with security in mind.

Not sure why you are having issues with the actual command you are trying to process, however my suggestion would be to use the [file_exists()](http://php.net/file_exists) or [glob()](http://php.net/glob) functions in php instead of going to the file system manually.

Comment: I also recommend this approach and DEFINITELY recommend against executing shell commands.  file_exists() and glob() will also normally work on both Windows and Linux servers, where exec commands will usually not.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all. Your suggestions really worked. It all worked well with glob().

May be the reason is executing shell command via php does not wait for sufficient time for the outcome Or it has something to do with the CGI mode where php is run.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: It could have something to do with the filesystem not having updated since the upload for the find to actually find it, or it could be the execution failed for some reason - either way avoid exec & shell_exec AT ALL COSTS (very very bad thing to use in general) - Oh and please accept answer above :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set:  `ignore_user_abort(true);`
and  `set_time_limit()` to something reasonable?
Try also with popen(). I always find it more easy to interface correctly.